# Passing string from one py to gui

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt4

Can someone tell me how do this?

I got main.py and gui.py (made in pyqt4).
The main.py runs some code, whatever, print "hello world" and I want to pass this string to gui.py in `listWidget.addItem()`.

So in main.py I did:

```
from gui import Ui_Form
send_str = "hello all"
ui.listWidget.addItem(send_str)
```

and I get the error:
`NameError: global name 'ui' is not defined`.

which points to gui.py as in gui.py is

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    Form = QtGui.QWidget()
    ui = Ui_Form()
    ui.setupUi(Form)
    Form.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

If i put both code in one py, all if working.
How to separate these two, since i want my main.py to execute in endless loop, and from time to time i want to open gui and check whats new value main.py going to send to window?

Comment: When you `import` a module it does not automatically make all the variables it defines globals in the script doing the `import`. You need to prefix them with the module name, like  `gui.ui` in this case. However, the portion of the code that defined `ui` is inside a `if __name__ == "__main__":`, so the variable won't get defined when the script is being imported—so you'll still have the problem even if you added the prefix.

Comment: Thanks for reply. I now have no clue how to make this work.
Idea is to have like "service" running as main py, and whenever its need run gui and check status or similar from service it self..

Comment: Is `gui.py` something you can change?

Comment: Yes, the gui.py is not that huge, its just listWidget box to see message and two buttons.

Comment: In that case you can change it so it defines a function that executes the code currently following the `if __name__ == "__main__":` (although you'll probably not want the `sys.exit()` at the end). After doing that `main.py` can `import gui` and then call `gui.do_stuff_with_a_Ui_Form(<args>)` as needed.

Answer (score 0):

First problem is that ui variable is local to the if **name** == "**main**"

Second problem is the if itself because that branch will not be activated when you import a module, that is similar to the main() in c

3rd problem: the gui in QT has to run in the main thread. This means that your algorithm needs to run in another thread (there is an alternative with timers but it is ugly and harder to implement)

See a tutorial on QT threads and use the signal-slot mechanism to comunitate between gui thread and algorithm thread.

Comment: Thanks to all of you guys for helping.